# Good CMS/Publishing platform with media plugin and nice urls

Tags: php, content-management-system, media, gallery

I'm looking for a good publishing platform with a good media gallery. I'll need to show several sorts of video and images, so a good media gallery is a must. I've tried drupal, but I don't like the node organization structure. I'm searching for a simple URL scheme, because in the future I may want to migrate my static html site to this platform.

So I prefer a platform where urls are like [www.mysite.com/parent/child/grandchild/page](http://www.mysite.com/parent/child/grandchild/page) kinda like the atlassian confluence urls (ex: confluence/display/TKB/Technical+Details).  This way I'll be able to make a simple script to migrate my static page to the dynamic version.

---

Edit: The CMS/publishing platform must run on PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something opensource? you can try looking at Drupal or Joomla. Although, I recommend Drupal.

But if you are looking for your enterprise, you should really look at Alfresco.

Answer (score 2):

I would heartily get behind Wordpress. It is targeted at the blogging community, but a lot of "serious" sites use it with much success:

- http://politicalticker.blogs.cnn.com/
- http://scobleizer.com/
- http://www.zeldman.com
- http://www.techcrunch.com/

It has many great media-handling plugins:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=gallery

and also can be customized to produce whatever URLs you want:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

I've used it to develop 4 sites so far, and it's easy to customize, and has a great user-base. FTW.

Answer (score 0):

There's been some growing buzz around [Concrete5](http://www.concrete5.org/) lately.  The URL scheme is easy and straight forward (you pick the slugs), and a full file/media manager and a [plug-in marketplace](http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/).  I've been using it for client work and it's a nice mix of brain-dead-easy to use for clients, while still being powerful enough for a developer who knows what they're doing.

Worth a look.

Comment: Some of the concrete 5 plugins are paid. I'm not interested in that.